# Can my pi server handle 1000 mysql queries per second?

Tags: mysql

I have a `raspberry pi 3` webserver.

When user gets into my app. App is sending a post request to my server every second to check if there are any messages for user.

The query is simple: `SELECT message FROM messages WHERE id=id`

I'm using `innodb` and `node js` for handling post requests.

Comment: Why not simply try it?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I haven't published the app yet.

Comment: It's not obvious how that is a requirement to load testing your mysql setup (and/or that service as a whole)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist So I don't have 1000 users to test it.